# Free OS X software to rotate video by 90 degrees

Tags: macos, video, software-rec

I took an AVCHD video in portrait mode but it plays in landscape on my computer. I want to convert it to .mp4 format so am looking for either AVCHD rotation or MP4 rotation by 90 degrees.

Any suggestions on free software for Mac OS X that will rotate an AVCHD or MP4 video by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 4):

A while back I was looking for exactly that.

I ended up with [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/). Free, runs on Macs and Windows, and has a great number of features to cut and convert videos (if you know where to find them in the rather clunky UI).

Quicktime Pro can do it, too, but that is not free.

Comment: sigh. It's free, but have you been able to get this to work? There is no rotate menu item / toolbar item, and the only "rotate" that I found was in the Export dialog, where it doesn't work properly; the video gets rotated but the frame does not. (imagine a portrait painting and frame where someone rotates the portrait 90 degrees to landscape orientation, but leaves the frame in portrait orientation, and then chops off the parts of the portrait that won't fit in the frame.)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. The video I rotated (through the Export dialog) was almost square, so I did not notice the problem. Let us know if you find another setting to fix that.